# Custom Regional formats - keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard, 13.10, language-support

- I leave in Belgium, I use my computer in English and I want **€** as
  my currency symbol. Is that possible in ubuntu ?
- My keyboard layout is US but I want to add FR language with US Intl
  layout, and FR as label. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to AU? Can you please restate your question to ask for a solution? "Is it possible?" is considered [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask), because the only possible answers are "yes" and "no", neither of which is helpful. Thanks and have a nice stay!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Ja. Oui. Jawohl.

Make English your language for menus and windows.

Make Nederlands(België), Français(Belgique)... your regional format for numbers, dates and currency amounts.

Choose English US (alternative international) for your keyboard

There's also an option to assign the currency symbol € to certain keys

How do you want to type characters like é, è, â, ç œ  ... ? You have to configure it.

Try it with a live distro, without installing.

But don't use 13.10. There are (at the moment) unsolved problems with Keyboard Layout Options.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

You can open `System Settings -> Language Support`, install the Belgium language and then select e.g. "French (Belgium)" in the Regional Formats tab.

As regards keyboard layouts, you set them from `System Settings -> Text Entry`.